# Imagemagick results of +transparent (remove all colors but one) produces color residues

Tags: colors, imagemagick, pixel, gimp

I have images generated. It's pixel-perfect images (no interpolation, 1 pixel=1color, 5 colors only, etc.)
I want to separate each color in different files, so I use ImageMagick CLI commands to obtain the unique-colors, then extract with the `+transparent` command.

But the results contains colors residues.

---

I actually use this process to separate each color from an image pixel-perfect generated (in other words, 1 pixel, 1 color, no interpolation, no close color, etc. for a total of exactly 5 colors).
First I extract all unique-colors :

```bash
convert <image.png> -unique-colors txt: > colors.txt
```

I got a list of the 5 colors as expected.
Then I use the following command to separate each color in a unique file with a loop script :

```bash
# #110F12 is one of the colors that could be found in the colors.txt
convert <image.png> +transparent "#110F12" <output.png>
```

When I open the output.png with `sxiv` (a Simple X Image Viewer) I see some color residues. **But** I can't see them if I open it with Gimp and display the image at 100% or more, so I was like it was nothing.
Because I also need to fill the extracted color to a plain black for a later use, I first did it with Gimp as following :

- I open the produced file by ImageMagick with Gimp
- I select the color with a Alt+Click on the layer (there is only one unique color, so it select the wanted pixels)
- I fill it with black
- Invert the selection and Suppr (because, even if I didn't see colors residues at 100% or more, at 50% or less, the residues are here, so to be sure, I suppress everything but the color selection).

Because I want to do the same inside a script, to not open Gimp at all, I modified the previous ImageMagick command to :

```bash
convert <image.png> +transparent "#110F12" -fill black -opaque "#110F12" <output.png>
```

But then, if I open both files *ImageMagick+Gimp Process* & *ImageMagick Only* with sxiv, the first one (Gimp) has no more color residues (even at =<50% display), the second one have some white outlines.

Here some screenshot of the result on `sxiv` (the background of sxiv is gray to see clearly see the residues, but in reality it's transparency). First one with additional Gimp process, second one with ImageMagick only.
Even if the image processing during the downloading show blurry images, the *Gimp one* has sharp edges/pixels, no color residues. However, the *ImageMagick only one*...

[image: Result of ImageMagick then Gimp]
[image: Result of ImageMagick only]

So, I conclude that the residues are real. But I don't know how to get the same result as I did with Gimp, but with ImageMagick only.

Here is a sample for testing. The image contains exactly 5 colors (It's pixel perfect generated), and one of them is #110F12. But the image downloader probably downgrade the quality so it will be blurred if you test it.

[image: sample of five colors]

Comment: The problem is likely your image viewer and how it treats transparency and how it expands your image for viewing.

Comment: I'm not sure. If it was only the image viewer and the way it treats transparency, both images, made with Gimps or ImageMagick should look the same. But it's not.

Comment: Not necessarily.  GIMP might possibly add transparency  slightly differently.

Comment: Make sure the background of the transparency is black in both GIMP and Imagemagick.  In Imagemagick, add -background black -alpha background after adding the transparency.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Sorry, English is not my native language.
In other hands, the white residues I noticed are there when I removed colors for black. **But** when I only extract the color channel, the image viewer show me, instead of white residues, colors residues from the others channel. So it cannot be the image viewer for me. No matter how the image viewer treats transparency, how could it shows residues from the removed colors ? They are supposed to be deleted ! It is necessary to have information saved somewhere for the image viewer to show these artifacts, no ?

Comment: What viewer did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ImageMagick v7, a command like this will separate an image into individual images, each with just one color from the input image on a transparent background...

Windows Syntax:

```
magick image.png -colors 5 ( +clone -unique-colors ) ^
   +swap -duplicate %[fx:u.w-1] -reverse ^
   +transparent %[pixel:u[-1].p{t,0}] +delete result%02d.png
```

That reads in the image, and in this case starts by reducing the total colors to 5. Inside parentheses it makes a clone of the image, then reduces that to a single pixel for each individual color with "-unique-colors". That will be used in the next part of the command as a reference image.

After the parentheses the input image is duplicated to make one for each color. Then the "+transparent" operation steps through all the images, and removes all the colors except one using that "-unique-colors" image as a reference.

It finishes by deleting that reference image, and outputting the 5 files named "result00.png, result01.png... etc."

EDITED TO ADD: You can start with the above command, and expand it a bit to write the 5 images *and* 5 matching images in just black with a Windows CLI command like this...

```
magick image.png -strip -colors 5 ( +clone -unique-colors ) ^
   +swap -duplicate %[fx:u.w-1] -reverse -background none ^
   +transparent %[pixel:u[-1].p{t,0}] +delete ^
   -background black -alpha background -write img_color-%02d.png ^
   -fill black -colorize 100 img_black-%02d.png
```

That will read the input image, separate it into 5 images, each with a unique color on a transparent background, and write those 5 image files. It continues the command by colorizing the 5 images to black, then writing those to files also.

The filename numbers will coincide, so the all black companion image to "img_color-00.png" will be "img_black-00.png", and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to use it on Linux, but I got the following error :
`magick: For function 'u', bad qualifier 'pt' at 'pt' @ error/fx.c/GetFunction/1969.`
I escaped the parenthesis, but I don't know how to resolve the said error.

Comment: I can't test this on a Linux right now, but I'd first try to put double quotes around that entire FX expression, like "%[pixel:u[-1].p{t,0}]".

Comment: Your EDIT works perfectly ! I have no more residues ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is how you enlarge your result to view it. You should not enlarge with interpolation. Here is the result of your command on my Mac.

`convert img.png +transparent "#110F12" -fill black -opaque "#110F12" output.png`

[image]

Here I have enlarged by 400% with no interpolation. There is no halo around the edges of the bright region.

[image]

Here I have enlarged by 400% with Lanczos interpolation. But here there is a halo around the edges due to the blending of bright and black background

[image]